# How to access vars outside item when using with_items?

Tags: ansible

I have a role which uses `with_items`:

```
- name: Create backup config files
  template:
    src: "config.yml.j2"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ project }}_{{ env }}_{{ item.type }}.yml"
  with_items:
    - "{{ backups }}"
```

I can access the `item.type`, as usual, but not `project` or `env` which are defined outside the collection:

deploy/main.yml

```
- hosts: ...
  vars:
    project: ...
    rails_env: qa

  roles:
    - role: ../../../roles/deploy/dolly
      project: "{{ project }}"
      env: "{{ rails_env }}"
      backups:
        - type: mysql
          username: ... 
          password: ...
```

The error I get is:

`Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ project }}'`

The template, `config.j2.yml`, is:

```
type: {{  item.type }}
project: {{ project }}
env: {{ env }}
database:
  username: {{ item.username }}
  password: {{ item.password }}
```

Comment: shouldn't you get an error while defining the same variable name twice. one for definition and declaration

Comment: How do you know you cannot access project or env; what **error** message do you get? Also, FWIW, one need not re-declare the `project` var on the `roles:` item, since it will be automatically visible to the role by the nature of it being in the `vars:` block

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I don't seem to be able to use `project` even though it is defined in the top level `vars`, I get `AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'project'`.

Comment: I feel you are leaving out some detail, since I am able to render that template just fine, and no where in your provided code is `project` referenced as an attribute; perhaps update your question with the whole story, and/or include `ansible-playbook -vvvv`

Comment: `project` is referenced in both the task and template file. The `-vvv` output for the task is [here](https://gist.github.com/krisleech/0080125ce9e74da882b0cbf0eb8270ad)

Comment: I wondered if this was because I was trying to define a var using the name of an existing var, `project: {{ project }}`, and this does seem to be the case. If I rename to `foo: {{ project }}`, no error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for can't redefine a var with the same name as an existing var, so `project: {{ project }}` will always fail with an error.

Instead `project` can be omitted and the existing definition, in `vars`, can be used.

```
- hosts: ...
  vars:
    project: ... # <- already defined here

  roles:
    - role: ../../../roles/deploy/dolly
      backups:
        - type: mysql
          username: ... 
          password: ...
```

If the var is not defined in `vars` can be defined in the role:

```
- hosts: ...
  vars:
    name: ...

  roles:   
    - role: ../../../roles/deploy/dolly
      project: "{{ name }}" # <- define here
      backups:
        - type: mysql
          username: ... 
          password: ...
```